# In terms of a research question, how many research articles is too few to answer it and how many research articles is too many?

Tags: research

I need to write a paper in 4 weeks with at least 7 annotated bibliographies and 3 of them from JSTOR or EBSCO.  The word limit is 2000-2200.

Comment: I'm assuming this is for a university/college assignment, in which case, have you tried discussing it with your supervisor, or someone else at the uni/college? If your paper has any specific guidelines regarding the required number of citations, they'd be the best person to ask about it.

Comment: Could you elaborate more please?

Comment: There is no numerical answer to this question. You keep researching until you have enough to support your thesis. If you do not have enough you keep researching.